# Floating menu jquery hover

Tags: jquery, css

I got this following floating menu on my site:

```
$(function() {
    var nav = $('nav');
    var nava = $('nav a');
    /* var navaOnHover = $('nav a:hover'); */
    var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    var $w = $(window);
    nav.css({ background: '#222' });
    $w.scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
        var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
        if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                transition: 'all 0.30s ease-in-out',
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                left: nav.offset().left,
                width: nav.width(),
                height: 59,
                background: '#315d90'
            });
            nava.css({
                color:'#fff'
            });
            /* navaOnHover.css({
            color:'#000'
            }); */
            isFixed = true;
        }
        else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
        {
            nav.css({
            height: 50,
                position: 'static',
                background:'#222'
            });
            nava.css({
                color:'#fff'
            });
            /* navaOnHover.css({
            color:'#000'
            }); */
            isFixed = false;
        }
    });
});
```

In the fourth, twenty one and forty one lines (marked at the start with /* and at the end with */) I tried to get `nav a:hover` which is responsible for on mouse over when the menu floats down.
Now this is not working, the variable `navaOnHover` does not get `nav a:hover` value.
How can I make it work in this way or other ways?
It's important because if you scroll down and later go up, the `hover` settings are changed, and the color `#fff` stays either if you hover or not.

If I'm not clear, look at the **[demo](http://jsbin.com/qerabuxo/1)** - scroll the page down and afterwards scroll it up.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot select elements with javascript with the `:hover` selector. Just put all your css in a css file, including their hover states and toggle certain classes when the topbar is fixed or not.

Comment: I don't think I understood. Could you please upload a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        var nav = $('nav');
        var nava = $('nav a');
        var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
        var isFixed = false;
        var $w = $(window);
        nav.css({ background: '#222' });
        $('nav a').hover(function(){
             $(this).css({'color':'black'})
             },function(){
                $(this).css({'color':'white'}) 
        })
        $w.scroll(function() {
            var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
            var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
            if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
                nav.css({
                    transition: 'all 0.30s ease-in-out',
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0,
                    left: nav.offset().left,
                    width: nav.width(),
                    height: 59,
                    background: '#315d90'
                });
                isFixed = true;
            }
            else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
            {
                nav.css({
                height: 50,
                    position: 'static',
                    background:'#222'
                });
                isFixed = false;
            }
        });
    });})
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  
But I have one more question, if I increase the default (not on-floating) width of the bar, how can I place the bar on the bottom?
Thanks!! Accepted!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can not select an element by using `:hover` in jQuery, that's why your code is wrong.

If you need two/more conditional hover state elements, prepare two/more css classes and write their own `:hover` in css style. In jQuery change class depending on your conditions then `:hover` will applied automatically.